# Symfony2 - Parent routes read instead

Tags: symfony, routes

I am working on Symfony2 project in which a kind of general bundle, let say CoreBundle, is managing all the routes (in this form, first.domain/a-route, second.domain/a-route, third.domain/a-route,...) of the website. Now I have been creating FirstBundle, SecondBundle, ThirdBundle with the idea to "transfer" the management of routes of each subdomain (firt, second, third,...) to the related bundle.

Beginning with the transfer of routes from CoreBundle to FirstBundle by editing /app/config/routing.yml file from:

resource: "@ProjectFirstBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

```
prefix: /
```

host: "{subdomain}.{domain}"

```
defaults: { _controller: ProjectFirstBundle:Public:aroute }

  domain: %project_domain%

requirements:

  domain: "%project_domain%"

  subdomain:  'first'
```

to:

project_first_aroute:

```
path:    /a-route

host: "{subdomain}.{domain}"

defaults: { _controller: ProjectFirstBundle:Public:aroute, domain: "%project_domain%" }      

requirements:

  domain: "%project_domain%"

  subdomain:  'first'
```

And of course I have created controller and view files using the same schema as CoreBundle (by making an adaptation -- inheritance for .twig files).

Now the problem is only parent route (that is CoreBunble /a-route route) is being read when running the URL first.domain/a-route.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post what your routes look like for the children?

Comment: Thanks for your interest to my post. "project_first_aroute" above is a route for a child bundle which is FirstBundle. And in the parent bundle the corresponding route look like this:project_core_a_route:
    pattern:  /a-route
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectCoreBundle:Public:aroute }

Comment: Why do you even have parent routes then?  What's the order that you are loading them?